# Continuous annuity calculation

Tags: calculus, finance, actuarial-science

This is a problem from Marcel Finan's Exam FM/2 course.  It is not homework but I am studying for the FM exam and trying to get through this.

You are given $\frac{d}{dt}\bar{s}_t$ = $(1.02)^{2t}$.  Calculate $\delta$.

So we will integrate to and get $\bar{s}_t$ = $\int{(1.02)^{2t}}dt$ = $\frac{(1.02)^{2t}}{2ln(1.02)}$ = $\frac{(1.02)^{2t}}{ln(1.02)^2}$.

This is where I get confused.  I can expand $\bar{s}_t$ since it equals $\frac{(1+i)^t-1}{\delta}$, but i don't have a value for $i$ explicitly defined in the problem.  I don't think $i$ = .02, so where do i go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, it is perhaps easier to use the fact that $$ \bar{s}_t = \frac{e^{t\delta} -1}{\delta}, $$
so that $$\frac{d}{dt}\bar{s}_t = e^{t\delta}= (1.02)^{2t}.$$ Taking natural log of both sides should give that $\delta = 2\log(1.02)$.

Comment: That is perfect!  Now i see it.  And that is the answer Finan gives.

Comment: Great! good luck with your preparation.